# Users and friends query with retry, returning JSON

Tags: c#, performance, error-handling, database, azure

I am new to Azure and SQL.  I have the following function that is part of a larger Web-API which is hosted on Azure and is querying an SQL Server database that is also hosted on the Azure platform:

```
[WebMethod]
public string RetrieveUserFriends(string userId)
{

    //Ensure there is a user id
    if (userId == null)
    {
        return "UserId is missing.";
    }

    //Build the Connection String
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = BuildConnection();

    //Build the query
    string query = string.Format("SELECT  u2.UserId, u2.[first name], u2.[last name], u2.[username] FROM       Users u1 INNER JOIN Friends f1 ON u1.userid = f1.userid INNER JOIN Users u2 ON u2.userid = f1.FriendId INNER JOIN Friends f2 ON u2.userid = f2.friendid WHERE   ( f2.userid = '{0}'    OR f1.friendid = '{0}') AND u2.userid != '{0}';", userId);

    try
    {

        //1. Define an Exponential Backoff retry strategy for Azure SQL Database throttling (ExponentialBackoff Class). An exponential back-off strategy will gracefully back off the load on the service.
        int retryCount = 4;
        int minBackoffDelayMilliseconds = 2000;
        int maxBackoffDelayMilliseconds = 8000;
        int deltaBackoffMilliseconds = 2000;

        ExponentialBackoff exponentialBackoffStrategy =
          new ExponentialBackoff("exponentialBackoffStrategy",
              retryCount,
              TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(minBackoffDelayMilliseconds),
              TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(maxBackoffDelayMilliseconds),
              TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(deltaBackoffMilliseconds));

        //2. Set a default strategy to Exponential Backoff.
        RetryManager manager = new RetryManager(new List<RetryStrategy>
{  
exponentialBackoffStrategy 
}, "exponentialBackoffStrategy");

        //3. Set a default Retry Manager. A RetryManager provides retry functionality, or if you are using declarative configuration, you can invoke the RetryPolicyFactory.CreateDefault
        RetryManager.SetDefault(manager, false);

        //4. Define a default SQL Connection retry policy and SQL Command retry policy. A policy provides a retry mechanism for unreliable actions and transient conditions.
        RetryPolicy retryConnectionPolicy = manager.GetDefaultSqlConnectionRetryPolicy();
        RetryPolicy retryCommandPolicy = manager.GetDefaultSqlCommandRetryPolicy();

        string json = string.Empty;

        //5. Create a function that will retry the connection using a ReliableSqlConnection.
        retryConnectionPolicy.ExecuteAction(() =>
        {

            using (ReliableSqlConnection connection = new ReliableSqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {

                connection.Open();

                IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = query;

                //6. Create a function that will retry the command calling ExecuteCommand() from the ReliableSqlConnection
                retryCommandPolicy.ExecuteAction(() =>
                {

                    using (IDataReader reader = connection.ExecuteCommand<IDataReader>(command))
                    {


                        List<GameOnUser> users = new List<GameOnUser>();

                        int count = reader.FieldCount;


                        while (reader.Read())
                        {

                            GameOnUser user = new GameOnUser();

                            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                            {

                                if (i == 0)
                                {
                                    user.ID = reader.GetGuid(i).ToString();
                                }
                                else if (i == 3)
                                {
                                    user.Username = reader.GetString(i);
                                }

                            }

                            users.Add(user);
                        }

                        json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(users);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return json;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        return "ERROR (RetrieveUserFriends): " + e.Message;
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: I am aware of the poorly named columns.  We intend to fix these in the near future.

My main concern lies in the area of the returning JSON:

```
string json = string.Empty;

            //5. Create a function that will retry the connection using a ReliableSqlConnection.
            retryConnectionPolicy.ExecuteAction(() =>
            {

                using (ReliableSqlConnection connection = new ReliableSqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
                {

                    connection.Open();

                    IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                    command.CommandText = query;

                    //6. Create a function that will retry the command calling ExecuteCommand() from the ReliableSqlConnection
                    retryCommandPolicy.ExecuteAction(() =>
                    {

                        using (IDataReader reader = connection.ExecuteCommand<IDataReader>(command))
                        {


                            List<GameOnUser> users = new List<GameOnUser>();

                            int count = reader.FieldCount;


                            while (reader.Read())
                            {

                                GameOnUser user = new GameOnUser();

                                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                                {

                                    if (i == 0)
                                    {
                                        user.ID = reader.GetGuid(i).ToString();
                                    }
                                    else if (i == 3)
                                    {
                                        user.Username = reader.GetString(i);
                                    }

                                }

                                users.Add(user);
                            }

                            json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(users);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            return json;
```

I have a feeling that it is prone to failure but I may be wrong. Any advice on this chunk would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

```
//Build the query
string query = string.Format("SELECT  u2.UserId, u2.[first name], u2.[last name], u2.[username] FROM       Users u1 INNER JOIN Friends f1 ON u1.userid = f1.userid INNER JOIN Users u2 ON u2.userid = f1.FriendId INNER JOIN Friends f2 ON u2.userid = f2.friendid WHERE   ( f2.userid = '{0}'    OR f1.friendid = '{0}') AND u2.userid != '{0}';", userId);
```

It appears you are using `string.Format` to insert query parameters.  The problem with this is that it opens up your API to SQL injection attacks.

For example, if someone were to somehow pass the following for userId:

```
' OR 1=1);
```

and an appropriate suffix so the overall query is valid SQL, it would return all users.  Other injected strings could do worse like modify/drop tables.

Instead, you want to use a parameterized query by replacing your format specifier with an @-prefixed variable.  Then, you can add parameters to the `SqlCommand.Parameters` collection:

```
const string QUERY = 
@"SELECT u2.UserId, u2.[first name], u2.[last name], u2.[username]
FROM Users u1
INNER JOIN Friends f1 ON u1.userid = f1.userid
INNER JOIN Users u2 ON u2.userid = f1.FriendId
INNER JOIN Friends f2 ON u2.userid = f2.friendid
WHERE ( f2.userid = @userId OR f1.friendid = @userId)
   AND u2.userid != @userId;";

using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = QUERY;
    command.Parameters.Add("@userID", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters[@"userID"].Value = userId;
}
```

As an aside, `IDbCommand` implements `IDisposable`, so you need to put the command object within a `using` statement.

Comment: Thanks Dan I had no idea (the more you know), I'll be sure to make the appropriate changes throughout my code.  Do you have any insight into how I am handling the response from the database?  It could be correct but that was my main concern until you mentioned the SQL injection hazard.

Answer (score 2):

This loop:

```
                            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                            {

                                if (i == 0)
                                {
                                    user.ID = reader.GetGuid(i).ToString();
                                }
                                else if (i == 3)
                                {
                                    user.Username = reader.GetString(i);
                                }

                            }
```

serves no purpose. Insead, just use

```
if (count > 0)
{
  user.ID = reader.GetGuid(0).ToString();
  if (count > 3)
  {
     user.Username = reader.GetString(3);
  }
}
```

Also, this seems like the kind of thing that LINQ (specifically [LINQ-to-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) is tailor-made for.